# What unit of measurement is \widthof using

Tags: width, unit-of-measure, calc

For various purposes I need to know the width of a given text. The easiest way to do this is to use the `\widthof{}` command from the `calc` package. Issue is that I can't understand what unit of measurement is this command using. I expected it to be `pt`, but the number gets so big that it can't possibly be that.

The following MWE, for instance, will print the value 2081098:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{calc}

\newcounter{a}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{a}{\widthof{asdasd}}
\thea

\end{document}
```

The package documentation doesn't indicate the unit of measurement.

Comment: Scaled points; 65536sp=1pt. But why using a counter? If `\mylen` is a length, `\settowidth{\mylen}{asdasd}` would store the width more easily.

Comment: this is nothing to do with `\widthof`, it is how _any_ length is cast to a counter, try `\setcounter{a}{\textwidth}` for example.

Comment: I was totally noob on the lengths matter. Now I see how to use them. Thanks everybody

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you do

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\newlength{\mylen}
\newcounter{a}

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\mylen}{asdasd}

\the\mylen

\setlength{\mylen}{\widthof{asdasd}}

\the\mylen

\end{document}
```

you get

> 31.75504pt
>   31.75504pt

If you add

```
\setcounter{a}{\mylen}
\thea
```

you get

> 2081098

because

```
31.75504 * 65536 = 2081098.30144
```

and TeX truncates this to an integer. The dimension in points is coerced to scaled points (65536sp = 1pt).